# Issue in importing module and invoking a function , circular import in python program

Tags: python, python-module, circular-dependency, pitch

I am trying to find the pitch of the audio using below code:

```
import sys
import pitch
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play


p = pitch.find_pitch('sample.mp3')
```

But, i am am getting below error:

```
AttributeError: partially initialised module 'pitch' has no attribute 'find_pitch' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

Please Help.

Comment: Did you put in the parameter for find_pitch() in your actual code ?

Comment: @RambarunKomaljeet Yes, i put sound.mp3 in parameter.